# Python : getting ValueError during comparison

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to check and compare length of a pandas dataframe `column` and check is the value of a dataframe column exists in a particular list and I have written below code for the same:

```
def validation(dataset,column,length): 
    dataset['A'] = 10
    if(len(column) < int(length)) & (dataset.A.isin(['10']).astype(int)):
        dataset['A']= 11


validation(df,df.name,2)
```

but during execution I am getting below error :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: what types are `dataset`, `column` and `length`? Can you give us an example of each (edit your question, don't reply)?

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution should be simplify - removed `column`, because same length like `df` and for condition need `and` because compare scalars with `any` for return at least one `True`.

Also `isin` is used for check multiple values, so for check one value use [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`):

```
def validation(dataset,length): 
    dataset['A'] = 10
    if(len(dataset) < int(length)) and dataset.A.eq('10').any():
    #for check multiple values
    #if(len(dataset) < int(length)) and dataset.A.isin(['10', '12']).any():
        dataset['A']= 11


validation(df,2)
```